# What's the difference between starting sidekiq inside rails directory and within an existing rails process (like console) using fork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-console

```
$ rails console

[1] pry(main)> fork { exec "bundle exec sidekiq -c 3 crawling_jobs -t 1 -L log/sidekiq.log" }
=> 7306

bundler: failed to load command: sidekiq (/Users/raducroitoru/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/sidekiq)
LoadError: cannot load such file -- selenium-webdriver
```

Same command works within project directory.

For me it appears to be something like bin PATH issue, but I can't find any topics in regards to this. Appreciate any help.

Ruby: 2.5.3, Rails: 4.2.11.1, Sidekiq: 5.2.7 (ent: 1.8.1)

Comment: Can you add your Gemfile to the question - it seems that the environment that you are running in isn't loading selenium (e.g. from the selenium-webdriver gem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the forked process most likely doesn't inherit the same environment as your running console, so bundler wont load the correct gems (and hence it can't find selenium-webdriver) - you *might* fix it by adding a rails env var to the command e.g.

```
fork { exec "RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env} bundle exec sidekiq -c 3 crawling_jobs -t 1 -L log/sidekiq.log"
```

I said "might" because your console env (`Rails.env`) may also not have the gem group for selenium-webdriver.

Although your question relates to firing this up from the console, is there a reason you need to do this from an existing rails process and not from the shell ?

Comment: The command was already with `RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env}` but your answer made me realise the grouping in Gemfile. I had the gem inside the test group, while the RAILS_ENV was staging in this case.

Comment: I don't want to start it from the console, it was just an example. I'll have to start it on demand (on user demand) for some ad hoc queues on staging. No production `exec` here :)